# How to add Animation Button like this?

Tags: swift, animation, button, uibutton

How can I create an animated and shadowed button like in this [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c2X9qzNQTicx62n6eW4O-PuA49YqXXhL/view)
(Once you click the button, it shines and swings)

Here is my code:
(This code implement swing and shadow but needs to be organized and arranged so that it is capable of running the light and the swing with one click and the button doesn't move from its place unnecessarily)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var aBtn: ButtonWithShadow!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func btnClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if sender.isSelected {
            sender.isSelected = false
            sender.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.50).cgColor
            sender.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
            sender.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
            sender.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0
            sender.layer.masksToBounds = false
        } else {
            sender.isSelected = true
            sender.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.0).cgColor

        }

        aBtn.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
        aBtn.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-.pi / 15, 0, 0, 1)
        let needleAnim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
        needleAnim.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        needleAnim.duration = 1.0 as? CFTimeInterval ?? CFTimeInterval()
        needleAnim.repeatCount = 5
        needleAnim.autoreverses = true
        // Setting fillMode means that, once the animation finishes, the needle stays in its end position.
        needleAnim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        needleAnim.isRemovedOnCompletion = true
        needleAnim.toValue = Double.pi / 15
        aBtn.layer.add(needleAnim, forKey: nil)
    }    
}
```

and

```
import UIKit

class ButtonWithShadow: UIButton {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        //updateLayerProperties()
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: You should describe what your code actually does, and what problems you are facing (e.g. what effects are missing).

Comment: This code implement swing and shadow but needs to be organized and arranged so that it is capable of running the light and the swing  with one click and the button doesn't move from its place unnecessarily

Comment: Please delete the 'answer' below and [edit] the information into the question above.

Comment: ok and i am so sorry about that , i am a new here and this is the first Question for me

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as written and provides a swinging button when clicked. Make sure you control-click dragged from the button to the button definition.

[image: swing button]

You'll need to add two images to your button, one for the off state and one for the on state.

[image: off]

and on

[image: on]

Here is the intermediate result of adding setting the images.

[image]

and the way to change the images is to add them to the assets catalog and then change them with :

```
if sender.isSelected {
        sender.isSelected = false
        sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "off"), for: .normal)
        sender.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.50).cgColor
        sender.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
        sender.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        sender.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0
        sender.layer.masksToBounds = false
    } else {
        sender.isSelected = true
        sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "onbtn"), for: .normal)
        sender.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.0).cgColor

    }
```

Comment: please tell me how to make the button do swing and light like the video ?

Comment: @Haitham to light up the image you will need to do two things. 1) use two different images - see my edit. and 2) you can add a layer to create the lighter shadow.

Comment: I know how to add one image to one button(1x , 2x , 3x ) but I do not know how to add two different images to one button

Comment: @Haitham updated answers to show how to change the two images after adding them to your assets. But at this point, this is rather basic stuff, please consider watching some swift or xCode tutorials about working with images and buttons.

Comment: @HaithamAbdelWahab, if this solution works for you, please up vote it.